# CreateProcess GetLastError 2

Tags: c, winapi

Мой код получает имя исполняемого файла по сокету (имя перед отправкой кодируется в UTF-16), и при попытке запустить получает код ошибки 2 из GetLastError.

```
const wchar_t* name;
wchar_t path[300];
wchar_t res[300];

recv(sock, name, 14, 0);

GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, 300);

wcsncat(res, name, wcslen(name));
wcsncat(res, L" ", 1);
wcsncat(res, path, wcslen(path));

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));

if(!CreateProcessW(NULL,res,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL, NULL,&si,&pi))
    {
        printf("Error code:%i", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

В тестовом варианте я заранее определял имя.

```
const wchar_t* name = L"ok.exe";
```

И это работало.
Почему отправляя тоже самое имя по сокету я получаю ошибку ?

Добавлю еще строку отправки с сервера на питоне.

```
s.send("gt.exe".encode("UTF-16"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, потому что память для `name` у вас не выделена, и в указателе содержится мусор. И записью по этому указателю вы портите память. А в вашем тестовом варианте он указывал на константную строку и все было нормально.

А еще вы не инициализируете массив `res` и в нем содержится непонятно что. А потом вы туда записываете строку функцией `wcsncat`, которая добавляет строку в конец той строки, которая содержится в `res`. А что за строка содержится в `res` и где "конец строки" у этих мусорных данных?

Вот уже в двух местах у вас происходит порча памяти. Хотя это проходит незамеченным (это только пока), но в `res` у вас явно содержится не то, что вы ожидали.

---

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ответы на вопросы из комментария)

1) Да, объявление wchar_t name[14] выделит память, но `const` там быть не должно - какая это константа, если вы туда пишете?

2) `recv` ожидает указатель на `char`, а не `wchar_t`, поэтому правильный вызов должен выглядеть как

```
recv(sock, (char*)name, sizeof(name), 0);
```

3) `wcsncat` не посылает данные в какой-то "результирующий массив", она производит конкатенацию двух существующих строк. Если у вас в первом массиве мусор, она вторую строку к мусору и добавит.

Нужно либо инициализировать массив пустой строкой, например, `res[0] = 0;`, либо использовать в первом вызове функцию копирования (`wcscpy`), а не конкатенации.

Comment: Я предполагаю wchar_t name[ 14 ]; выделит память ? Если да, то что нужно передать в recv( ) чтобы не было "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" ? Я думал что res необходим как результирующий массив, содержащий после конкатенации имя, пробелы и кавычки. Мне нужно что-то поместить туда прежде чем складывать строки ? Как мне его проинициализировать если мне не нужно чтобы внутри него до конкатенации что-то было ?

Comment: @rootkit.sys, дополнил ответ.

Comment: C recv понял.

А вот с wcsncat не совсем.

Если никакой 3-й массив не нужен, куда попадет сложенная из двух строка ?

Как она складывает строку, например из 10 и 5 символов ?

В итоге символов получается 15, но ни под одну из строк 15 байт памяти не выделено.

Об этом должен заботиться программист ?

Как, если я знаю что размер строки должен быть больше того что есть сейчас, выделить под нужное кол-во памяти ?

Comment: @rootkit.sys, `wcscat/wcsncat` дописывает вторую строку в конец первой. Первый массив должен быть достаточно большим, чтобы вместить обе строки плюс завершающий ноль. Да, это забота программиста.

Comment: Не сработало, та же ошибка.

Для проверки правильности имени создавал файл и заметил особенность, что если имя файла передать такое же как имя какого-нибудь другого файла из папки - он создает 2 файл с таким же точно именем -_-

Comment: я думаю что ошибка тут все-таки в сервере который кодирует строку в UTF-16, как таковой информации о создании массива типа wchar_t на питоне я не нашел, и идея закодировать обычную строку в UTF-16 похоже была не лучшей

Comment: @rootkit.sys, вы посмотрите что в строке содержится, выведите ее в какой-нибудь временный файл прямо в двоичной форме. Очень сложно понять что происходит не зная исходных данных.